# How to use the not selector to target elements inside an ID?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use the not css selector to target all elements except all the elements of type INSIDE (a child of) a class or ID?

Example: target all svg files except the ones inside the `widget` element:

```
svg:not(#widget) {
  fill: red;;
}

<div>
 <svg /> // red
 <div id="widget">
  <svg /> // not red
  <svg /> // not red
 </div>
 <svg /> // red
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `svg {
  fill: red;
}
#widget svg {
  fill: initial;
}`. Don't think you can do something like `:not(#widget svg)` because that wouldn't be a simple selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
svg {
  fill: red;
}

#widget svg{
  fill : inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <svg style='width:200px;height:200px;' /> // red
 <div id="widget">
  <svg style='width:200px;height:200px;'  /> // not red
  <svg style='width:200px;height:200px;'  /> // not red
 </div>
 <svg style='width:200px;height:200px;'  /> // red
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
    color: black;
}
div:not(#widget){
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <svg /> // red
 <div id="widget">
  <svg /> // not red
  <svg /> // not red
 </div>
 <svg /> // red
</div>
```